# connection failed: FATAL: role "y" does not exist when .ini has role "x"

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, users, authentication

I have a Python program for PostgreSQL database management. Today it started throwing

```
psycopg.OperationalError: connection failed: FATAL:  role "role_a" does not exist
```

Connection parameters have not been changed. My `database.ini` file from which the `psycopg connection` parameters are parsed has `user=postgres` instead of `role_a` which is my Ubuntu username and the connection worked before today. I tried changing `trust` to `peer` in `postgresql pg_hba.conf` file but it did not change the error. The file has following lines now:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

How can I regain connection to my database? Supposedly creating a role with my Ubuntu username could help? I'd be more satisfied to connect with the user `postgres` because I have been using that this far. If creating a role for Ubuntu user is the only option, then how do I do that?
The `.ini` file I use for parsing `psycopg connection` parameters is as follows:

```python
[fwe]
host=localhost
dbname=fwe_db
user=postgres
password=postgres

[create]
host=localhost
port=5432
user=postgres
password=postgres
autocommit=True
```

Section `create` was used to create the database and section `fwe` was used afterwards for inserts and queries.

Comment: postgres doesn't have ini files.  Your questions seems to be about python, or some unstated library/framework within python, but you haven't shown any code for either.

Comment: @jjanes Code added, psycopg explicitly mentioned now. The site does not have a tag for psycopg, maybe on purpose?

Comment: Yes, that is on purpose, because such questions belong on Stackoverflow.